# Using Tweepy to retrieve all tweets containing a particular hashtag for an account ID

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

Im currently getting all the tweets for a hashtag from a particular account.

By using this I can get hashtags' tweets :

```
   tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q='#marketing', rpp=100).items(10)
```

By using this I can get tweets of a parituclar Id:

```
   tweepy.Cursor(api.user_timeline, id="someid")
```

I need to combine these two to get all the tweets for a particular hashtag from an account.
I've tried multiple approaches to combine the above two api calls.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the search API with the parameter `q='#marketing from:user'` to get tweets from `@user` containing `#marketing`.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use:

```
tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q="from:screen_name #hashtag")
```

Example:

```
tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q="from:someid #marketing")
```

This issue was raised in [the tweepy github repo](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/issues/1177).
They should have added it in the documentation.